OpenSSL EVP_EncryptInit fail, while called in destructor
Recently i tried to improve my crash handler, and write logs about when objects are being destroyed. I use singleton pattern for each global object, and have function which initialize them in correct order (crash handler is last one)
But i found strange behavior of aes encrypt, everything works fine except the situation when the app is being closed, and all destructors are being called.
void shutdown() {
    dbg_println("Application shutdown");
    secure_string key = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
    secure_string iv = "1234567890123456";
    secure_string out;
    int res = secure_crypto::aes_encrypt(key, iv, "shutdown", out);
    if (res != 0) {
        dbg_println("Application aes_encrypt failed {}", res);
    }
}

That function is called in destructor of Application - object which is created at the end - so destructor is called first
AES Encrypt code i use:
using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)>;

int secure_crypto::aes_encrypt(const secure_string &key, const secure_string &iv, const secure_string &plainText,
                               secure_string &encryptedText) {
    dbg_println("Encrypting {} with key {} and messageIv {}",
                plainText.size() > 500 ? "..." : secure_crypto::secure_string_to_hex(plainText),
                secure_crypto::secure_string_to_hex(key), secure_crypto::secure_string_to_hex(iv));

    try {
        /*
        * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
        * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
        * In this example we are using 256-bit AES (i.e. a 256-bit key). The
        * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
        * is 128 bits
        */

        if (key.size() != 32 || iv.size() != 16) {
            return -1;
        }

        const auto *keyArr = (const unsigned char *) key.c_str();
        const auto *ivArr = (const unsigned char *) iv.c_str();

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);
        secure_vector<unsigned char> keyV(keyArr, keyArr + key.size());
        secure_vector<unsigned char> ivV(ivArr, ivArr + iv.size());

        dbg_println("Encrypting with key {} and iv {} and status: {}", secure_crypto::secure_string_to_hex(keyV),
                    secure_crypto::secure_string_to_hex(ivV), ctx.get() == nullptr ? "null" : "not null");
        int rc = EVP_EncryptInit(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc(), keyArr, ivArr);
        if (rc != 1) {
#if LOG_CRYPTO_ERRORS
            printf("err: %s", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
            dbg_println("[crypto] Error while aes encrypting: {}", rc);
#endif
            return -2;
        }

        // Recovered text expands upto BLOCK_SIZE
        encryptedText.resize(plainText.size() + BLOCK_SIZE);
        int out_len1 = (int) encryptedText.size();

        rc = EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx.get(), (unsigned char *) &encryptedText[0], &out_len1,
                               (const unsigned char *) &plainText[0],
                               (int) plainText.size());
        if (rc != 1) {
            return -3;
        }

        int out_len2 = (int) encryptedText.size() - out_len1;
        rc = EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx.get(), (unsigned char *) &encryptedText[0] + out_len1, &out_len2);
        if (rc != 1) {
            return -4;
        }

        // Set cipher text size now that we know it
        encryptedText.resize(out_len1 + out_len2);

        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
#if LOG_CRYPTO_ERRORS
        dbg_println("[crypto] Error while aes encrypting: {}", e.what());
#endif
        return -99;
    }
}

And the result in app:
Application shutdown
Encrypting 73687574646f776e with key 3132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233343536373839303132 and messageIv 3132
3334353637383930313233343536
Encrypting with key 3132333435363738393031323334353637383930313233343536373839303132 and iv 3132333435363738393031323334
3536 and status: not null
err: error:00000000:lib(0)::reason(0)
[crypto] Error while aes encrypting: 0
Application aes_encrypt failed -2

Any ideas what may be wrong in that code?

Perhaps OpenSSL is already unloaded by the time shutdown() is called? Maybe you are experiencing C++ initialization order fiasco and your globals are not cleaned up in the order you think they are? Who knows. There is no way to diagnose your issue with the limited information you have provided. Can you create a [mcve] that exhibits the same behavior?

Okay I'd prepare such example, and about order of object destruction - I'm sure about the order because I print message about if object is being destroyed. Without using openssl encryption there - all objects are being destroyed in correct order @RemyLebeau

Rebuild OpenSSL in debug mode and step inside EVP_EncryptInit.
